# Wait for window.open pop up to load before running rest of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I've been working on this for ages, trying to you win.load(), win.ready() etc etc, but with no success, I'm trying to user the flot function to right to a pop out child window, however I've not found a way to get the function to wait for the dom to have fully loaded. Thus each time I let it run naturally it complains it can't find the div to write to. When using the debugger it works fine if I use firebug to paude after the window open and let it run again.

```
   if (newwindow) {
        var win = window.open("pop_up.htm", 'window', "height=400,width=900");

        $.plot($("#pie_chart", win.document), data,
        {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    show: true
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $.plot($(graph_id), data,
        {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    show: true
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Well I got this far, it works in FF but not in IE6.... any ideas?

```
function generatePieChart(graph_id, objData, hyperlinks, newwindow) {

    var data = objData;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var num = parseInt(objData[i][1]);
        if (hyperlinks == true) {
            data[i] = { label: "<a class='user_pie_link super_light_box' id='" + objData[i][0] + "'>" + objData[i][0] + " <span style='float: right;'>" + objData[i][1] + "</span></a>", data: num }
        }
        else {
            data[i] = { label: "<p id='" + objData[i][0] + "'>" + objData[i][0] + " <span style='float: right;'>" + objData[i][1] + "</span></p>", data: num }
        }
    }

    if (newwindow) {

        var win = window.open("pop_up.htm", "window", "height=400, width=900");
        win.moveTo(50, 50);

        $(win.document).load(function () {
            generatePopOutPieChart(win, data);
        });

    }
    else {
        $.plot($(graph_id), data,
        {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    show: true
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

function generatePopOutPieChart(win, data) {

    $.plot($("#pie_chart", win.document), data,
        {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    show: true
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: you can do it if you have access to the page that will open in the popup. You set a variable that will call the `window.opener` - than you can control that boolean in your main file script after intervals checks and proceed with your code.

Comment: I do have access to the page being opened and opening, it's all local.

Comment: well than... Google for **popup window.opener**

Comment: Is the issue here one of timing? Or being able to access the div in the child pop-up?  Regardless, why not move the plotting call to the "pop_up.htm"?  That solves both problems.